# How do I make changes to the mesh when I've already started to make animations?

Tags: animation, maya

I'm animating a character with bones, using keyframes. The character is made up of a skeleton and a bunch of planes attached to that. I want to edit the scale of one of the planes, but when I do that, every animation keyframe that I have already overrides that and sets it back to the value it had when I started animating.

Is there a way to make changes to the mesh and propagating that change throughout the existing keyframes?

Pardon my Maya-illiteracy.

Answer (score 1):

Questions like this are probably better suited to the [CG Forums](http://forums.cgsociety.org/)

I'll try and answer it for you though as I have a background in Maya.

I'm assuming you have the planes either parented or constrained to the joints (bones). If this is the case, you can easily fix this (It is messier if they are bound to the skeleton)

By what you are describing, I think you have been keying all in your animations (including scale). You need to break the connection of your scale on the plane you are trying to re-scale, otherwise it will always be controlled by the keying you've applied to it.